# Inserting a node before a specific node in a linked list

Tags: c

So as the title says this code is to insert a node (newnode) before a specified node (i). newnode gets its values, re and im from the argument. I made a loop with b as its counter to find the node before i so that I could modify the next pointer for the node before i.
The function to get i, find_closest works and isn't the problem.

When I run this, I get segmentation error and I can't understand why. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```c
    void insert_before_closest (struct node_t **head, float re, float im)
        {
          struct node_t *i = find_closest(*head, re, im); 
          
          //creates new node
          struct node_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
          newnode->re = re;
          newnode->im = im;
          
          //if the closest node is at the head
          if (i==*head)
          {
            newnode->next = *head;
            *head = newnode;
          }
        
          else
          {
            newnode->next = i;
        
            //needs the node before i to point at a 
            struct node_t *b = *head;
            while (b->next != i)
            {
              b = b->next;
            }
            b->next = newnode;
          }
        }
```

Edit:
This is how the find_closest function, which basically returns a node closest to a specified point in an argand diagram (real and imaginary values) using pythagoras:

```c
    struct node_t *find_closest(struct node_t *head, float re, float im)
    {
        struct node_t *found = head;
        float sml = 100000;
        float dist = 0;
        
        for (struct node_t *i = head; i != NULL; i = i->next)
        {
            dist = sqrt(pow(i->re - re, 2) + pow(i->im - im, 2));
            
            if (dist < sml) 
            {
                sml = dist;
                found = i;
            }
        }
        return found;}
```

Edit 2: making a small int main function, but only contains the head and one more node after it.

```
    struct node_t {
    float re,im;
    struct node_t *next;
    };typedef struct node node_t;
    
    
    int main (void) {
        struct node_t *head= malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
        struct node_t *node1= malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
        float re,im;
    
        head->next = node1;
        float re, im;
        scanf(" %f &f", &re, &im);
        head->re = re;
        head->im = im;
    
        scanf(" %f &f", &re, &im);
        node1->re = re;
        node1->im = im;
        printf("inserting before closest node);
        scanf(" %f &f", &re, &im);
        insert_before_closest(head,re,im);
```

Edit 3: I found my mistake, it was inputting head instead of &head, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Use pen and paper to draw up the list and the operations you perform on it, at the same time (using boxes for nodes and arrows for links, erase and redraw arrows as needed).

Comment: If you want more help from us, then please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (including how you initialize the list, how you call this function, and the `find_closest` function), and also point out where in the code the crash happens (caught by using a debugger).

Comment: it might be that the `b->next` is reaching the end of the list without finding `i` - a situation that is not accounted for by that condition. Would have to know how `find_closest` works to confirm that though

Comment: Probably not the problem but your code never check for `*head` being NULL.

Comment: *"When I run this"* - which we cannot do. Further, *"The function to get i, find_closest works and isn't the problem."* - it's a *big* problem if it works, but doesn't give you what you actually need, which is a pointer by address (i.e. a pointer to pointer, in much the same fashion as the `head` pointer argument).

Comment: The bug isn't in the posted code. **BUT** the code makes a number of assumption about how it's called and the return value from a function. As we don't have that code, we can't help.

Comment: I would like to see 1) how the list is initialized 2) how the first element is added 3) how this function is called 4) what `find_closest` is doing

Comment: In the initialization, you miss `head->next = NULL`

Comment: Why can't you post a simple `main` function that shows it all? If you want help....

Comment: Any decent compiler should have been warning you about passing wrong argument types to the `insert_before_closest` function. As seen in e.g. [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/nr7En5). Please always treat warnings as errors that *must* be fixed.